# Android studio code problem specification

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to ask, why does my laptop take so long to run and build applications on Android Studio Code?  and what is the minimum specification to use android studio code.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, I would recommend getting yourself an SSD and Upgrading your RAM to 8GB at least.

Thank you and I hope this might help. Happy Coding.